# After using unset($form['author']); for comment module drupal returns errors

Tags: 7, forms, comments

As I would like to allow users print their names with comments I added a new field called comment_name. To not have 2 fileds with name I used the code to unset filed "name" from comment.module

```
function user_add_node_form_comment_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
unset($form['author']);
return $form;
}
```

But after adding a comment I receive an error message

```
Notice: Undefined index: name in function comment_form_validate() (line 2127 in file D:\sites\theme\www\modules\comment\comment.module).
Notice: Undefined index: mail in function comment_form_validate() (line 2140 in file D:\sites\theme\www\modules\comment\comment.module).
Notice: Undefined index: homepage in function comment_form_validate() (line 2143 in file D:\sites\theme\www\modules\comment\comment.module).
```

I guess it because I unset a form that has to validate if user logged in or not but don't know how to solve it.

P.S. Also I use the Ajax Comments Module

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should try this if you just want to hide the comment default name field !

```
function user_add_node_form_comment_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form['author']['name']['#access'] = FALSE;
}
```

Comment: thank you, your variant of function works, but if user user "preview button" before posting comment drupal returns an error: "Notice: Undefined index: format in function comment_preview() (line 2057 in file D:\sites\theme\www\modules\comment\comment.module).
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$thread in function ajax_comments_entity_prepare_view() (line 375 in file D:\sites\theme\www\sites\all\modules\ajax_comments\ajax_comments.module)."

Comment: well, it was my mistake in ajax comment module configuration. Thanks for help!